# Actualizar ComboBox

Tags: c#, combobox

Tengo una clase con `public static List<Persona> Personas { get; set; }` donde se guardan personas.

luego en el formulario principal al cargar

```
 private void Principal_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        recargar_CBPersonas();
    }

  public void recargar_CBPersonas()
    {
        CBPersonas.DisplayMember = "Nombre";
        CBPersonas.ValueMember = "DNI";
        CBPersonas.DataSource = Gestion.Personas;
    }
```

y en el formulario principal se abre otro formulario donde se llenan los datos

```
private void registrarToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IngresoPersona ingresopersona = new IngresoPersona();
        ingresopersona.ShowDialog();
        recargar_CBPersona();
    }
```

Habia leido en internet que de esta forma se recargaba el ComboBox pero al cerrar el formulario donde se registran las personas el ComboBox sigue vacio. se que los datos se estan guardando bien porque tengo una funcion para buscar por CI y si funciona correctamente.

Observacion*: Si quito estas lineas:

```
private void Principal_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    recargar_CBPersonas();
}
```

Y agrego mi primer objeto a la lista al cerrar el formulario de registro, se actualiza el combo y sale el objeto, pero al agregar el segundo objeto queda igual y solo muestra el primero.

Edito*: Lo solucione de esta forma, no se si sea la mas indicada pero por ahora hace lo quiero:

```
    public void recargar_CBPersona()
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Clear();
        foreach(Persona pers in Gestion.Personas)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(pers);
        }
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Nombre";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "DNI";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Revisa si cambias tu clase de esta manera, hice la prueba y funciono, también chequea que tengas elementos dentro de tu lista:

```
public void recargar_CBPersona()
{
    List<Persona> Personas = new List<Persona> {
        new Persona("Maria Martinez", "123456"),
        new Persona("Jose Franco", "123456"),
        new Persona("Alberto Urdaneta", "123456")
    };
    comboBox1.DataSource = Personas;
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Nombre";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "DNI";
}

public class Persona
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string DNI { get; set; }
    public Persona(string nombre, string dni)
    {
        Nombre = nombre;
        DNI = dni;
    }
}
```

Realizando una prueba obtuve lo siguiente:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Gestion.Personas = new List<Persona>();
        Gestion.Personas.Add(new Persona("Maria Martinez", "123456"));
        Gestion.Personas.Add(new Persona("Jose Franco", "123456"));
        Gestion.Personas.Add(new Persona("Alberto Urdaneta", "123456"));
        recargar_CBPersona();
    }

    public void recargar_CBPersona()
    {
        CBPersonas.DataSource = Gestion.Personas;
        CBPersonas.DisplayMember = "Nombre";
        CBPersonas.ValueMember = "DNI";
    }

    public class Gestion
    {
        public static List<Persona> Personas { get; set; }
    }

    public class Persona
    {
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string DNI { get; set; }
        public Persona(string nombre, string dni)
        {
            Nombre = nombre;
            DNI = dni;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No cambie nada la verdad, lo unico que tenia de diferente era que mi constructor estaba vacio, creaba el objeto de forma diferente, pero igual sigue pasando lo mismo, como dije tengo una funcion para buscar en la lista y si funciona bien. otra cosa. si quito el load del formulario principal, al agregar el primer elemento a la lista se actualiza el combo pero al agregar el segundo elemento queda igual, con el primero y no se actualiza mas.

Comment: El buscador puede funcionar bien es otro método, debes es chequear que no se pierda la información con un breakpoint justo en esa línea de código CBPersonas.DataSource = Gestion.Personas; volví a realizar una prueba y funciona bien. Agregando elementos uno a uno manualmente. Algo en tu código esta afectando tu lista.

Comment: volvi a realiza una prueba en un solo form, solo tenia un metodo para actualizar el combo y para agregar los nombre y tampoco se actualizaba, la verdad no se que es pasando..

Answer (score 0):

Te falta controlar el resultado del dialogo, así como lo tienes recarga el combo al mismo tiempo que abre el dialogo, lo que deseas es que al cerrar el dialogo recargue el combo para eso intenta lo siguiente:

En tu dialogo en la acción de guardar y cerrar debes indicarle que el dialogo se cerrara con estatus OK

```
this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
this.Close();
```

Y cuando abres el dialogo vas a recibir ese parámetro

```
IngresoPersona ingresopersona = new IngresoPersona();
if (DialogResult.OK == ingresopersona.ShowDialog(this))
{
    recargar_CBPersona();
}
```

Comment: No creo que que lo que indica @shop350 sea el problema, el método recargar_cbpersonas() se llama siempre después de cerrar la ventana, devuelva lo que devuelva el showdialog. Has probado que tienes datos en la lista?prueba a poner MesaageBox.Show(Gestión.Personas.Count().ToString()); en el método recarga. Si obtienes el valor 0 o nulo es que no estas cargando nada en la lista. Y si sale distinto de 0 debería salir en el Combo una lista de opciones, revisa el valuemember y displaymember. Saludos

Comment: Nada, no funciono. @Juanjo `MesaageBox.Show(Gestión.Personas.Count().ToString())` muestra correctamente la cantidad de elementos actuales de la lista, los atributos de mi clase persona a los que estan asociados los member son `public string Nombre { get; set; }public int DNI { get; set; }`

Comment: Prueba a cambiar el orden de la asignación de propiedades al combo, pon primero el datasource y luego los otros dos (value y display)

Comment: tambien lo hice, y sigue igual.. no hay que cambiar nada en las propiedades del combo? de todos modos no toque nada cuando lo cree.